# Not full URL in Referer header in Visualforce since Spring '17

Tags: visualforce, http, platform-bug, spring17

I have a Visualforce page and controller relying on the HTTP Referer header.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer')
```

Before my org was upgraded to Spring '17 this returned e.g.:

```
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/apex/any.page
```

Now it only returns the host without the url path:

```
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer the [Salesforce Spring ’17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_security_other_changes.htm), this was implemented to enhance security of the platform.

> **Updated Referer Header**
>
> When loading assets outside of Salesforce, or navigating outside of Salesforce, the referer header shows only salesforce.com rather than the entire URL. This feature eliminates the potential for a referer header to reveal sensitive information that could be present in a full URL, such as an org ID. The updated referer header feature is supported only for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What is meant by "loading assets outside of Salesforce" and "navigating outside of Salesforce"? I an doing a redirect to a Salesforce Knowledge article inside of Salesforce.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it should still work internally...

Comment: @AdrianLarson it does but not in pages that have an action tag. I solved my problem by not redirecting server-side using <apex:page action=""/> but using a JS client side redirect.